# How to extract tar.gz on windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, tar, gz

Can anyone suggest me ways to extract tar.gz file on windows xp ? Is there any built-in tool ? Or may be a script that can be written ?

PS: Please note I can't install new software on my computer (do not have admin privileges).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484133/whats-a-good-tar-utility-for-windows

Comment: @Excellll with the exception of unxutils all these need to be installed explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to install the windows version of [tar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) and [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/), you just need to download 3 zip files, one which contains binaries for tar, one with the binaries for gzip and lastly the other contains the dependancies. Unpack the files, and follow the manual installation instructions, which tells you which files to copy from the dependency directory to the tar tool directory.

You can then run the tar command from the command line to unpack the tar.gz file with the commands

```
 gunzip.exe example.tar.gz

 tar.exe xf example.tar
```

If you can't download these files there is no other way to do it that I know of.

Comment: 7z is better, no need to type 2 different commands like that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc and 7z doesn't have an installer?

Comment: 7z can run portably, it doesn't need to be installed like winrar

Answer (score 1):

Use [7zip](http://www.7zip.org) to open tar.gz archives.

Answer (score 0):

winrar is open source and can do most compression files

Answer (score 0):

You can use 7zip portable http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable the app runs portable you don't have to be admin to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try online services such as http://www.wobzip.org/. You probably need two passes to extract your files; extract .gz contents, download the file then extract .tar ones

Answer (score 0):

or hamster :)
http://hamster-free-zip-archiver.en.softonic.com/

i think not only with tar.gz you'll have problem in the future.